# DevExpress XtraReport.LoadLayout падает на Windows10

Tags: c#, .net, администрирование, windows-10, devexpress

Проблема возникает на некоторых машинах где установлена Windows 10. Что интересно, то на большинстве машин всё работает, но на некоторых появляется ошибка.

[image: скрин с ошибкой]

Текст ошибки говорит о том, что не найдена dll, которая по всей видимости создается DevExpress динамически, в темповую папку. Но почему то в конкретном случае это не происходит. Причем я пробовал создавать файлы в этой директории и файлы создаются. Я не системный администратор и не знаю тонкостей, но права у пользователя максимальные, которыя я смог задать.Видно что падает в методе

```
XtraReport.LoadLayout(String) Method
```

Я задал этот вопрос на форуме DevExpress.[ссылка на вопрос](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T481201). Но предварительно просмотрев гугл и  тот же форум, предполагаю, что они открестятся от него. На самом деле я даже не уверен, что эта их проблема, поэтому пишу сюда! Если кто раньше встречался с подобной проблемой, откликнитесь! Буду очень признателен за помощь! Пишите в комментариях если нужна какая-либо дополнительная информация!

Comment: Могу посоветовать две вещи: 1. Подписаться на событие AppDomain.FirstChanceException и записывать в лог все исключения, с колстеком и время когда оно произошло. Если CSharpCodeGenerator не создает файл, это может быть вызвано в том числе и исключением. 2. Если проблема стабильно воспроизводится, не помешает также проанализировать лог инструмента [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Возможно вам удастся выявить таким образом подозрительную активность.

Comment: @Uranus Я подписался на событие AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException, но в момент падения, "ексепшен" не ловится в домене моего приложения. Всё равно выскакивает системная ошибка! Используя Process Monitor,  пока не удается ничего раскопать. P.S. Отвечал вам так долго, потому что ошибка у клиента которые работает только в будни! И только там воспроизводится ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема достаточно понятна - когда писали программу (скорее всего компонент XtraReport) путь для копирования dll в одном месте программы задали жестко (например что-то типа C:\Windows\Temp), а в другом - запрашивали путь у операционной системы.
Даже если это ошибка DevExpress, как показывает мой опыт чинить они вряд ли будут (в лучшем случае это займет немало времени) и нужна будет актуальная лицензия и пересборка основной программы.
У меня была похожая ошибка с этим компонентом, но не с dll, а с бланком отчета - после экспорта XtraReport использовал путь к шаблону не тот что указан в программе, а папку экспорта.

Возможные решения:

1. Попробуйте найти эту dll (например на машине с другой версией Windows) и положить в папку C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\
   Если это поможет, вы можете сделать симлинк на эту dll из другой папки.
2. Если dll не имеет постоянного имени (меняется при каждом отчете), вам придется схитрить - програмно отлавливать новые dll там где они появляются (скорее всего это C:\Windows\Temp\, но надо отследить) и копировать их в C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ Это может сделать достаточно простая программа.
3. Попробуйте запустить программу в режиме эмуляции Windows XP. Возможно это подставит старый формат пути в программу.

В любом случае начинать надо с поисков что это за dll и куда она сохраняется. Если не находите - посмотрите ее не под Windows 10.